# Check Android image size before load to memory

Tags: android

I've created small app that works with images from gallery or camera.

It all works fine, but.
On device with small screen and small memory size (HTC Desire) I have some images downloaded in full size from other mobile phone, and they are much larger (8MP camera on that phone).

If I try to load that, for my small camera huge image, it will crash immediately.

So, how to implement some kind of check and to downsize that image, but still load it properly?

I do scale images down after they are loaded, but this is something that should be done before the crash appears.

Tnx.

```
           InputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // get picture size.
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // resize the picture for memory.
            int screenH = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels; //800
            int screenW = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels; //480
            int width = options.outWidth / screenW;
            int height = options.outHeight / screenH;

            Log.w("Screen Width", Integer.toString(width));
            Log.w("Screen Height", Integer.toString(height));

            int sampleSize = Math.max(width, height);
            options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            try {
                in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // convert to bitmap with declared size.
            Globals.INSTANCE.imageBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can avoid load the bitmap in memory just setting

```
inJustDecodeBounds = true
```

[inJustDecodeBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds) will allow you to decode only the bounds of  the image without decode it. Given `height` and `width` of your bitmap you can downsampling it using.

[inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize)

as the doc stays:

> If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original
>   image, returning a smaller image to save memory.

```
int tmpWidth = bitmapWidth;
int tmpHeight = bitmapHeigth;
int requiredSize = ...
while (true) {
 if (tmpWidth / 2 < requiredSize
    || tmpHeight / 2 < requiredSize)
        break;
    tmpWidth /= 2;
    tmpHeight /= 2;
    ratio *= 2;
 }
```

EDIT: for a 32 bit `Bitmap` the memory required is  `width * height * 4`

Comment: I must admit, I'm not getting your answer. I'll edit my question with the code.

Comment: So I try to fit it on any screen, reading screen size, and possibly screen density, but it's still to big. I must be missing something regarding ratio / density.

Comment: I think it's to big (800 or 480). try setting inSampleSize = 8

Comment: I get strange situation, If I try to set it up manually, SampleSize 3 keeps my image twice bigger than I'd like to be, SampleSize 4 makes it to small...

Comment: can't be true. If you set inSampleSize to 3 the result image have to be 1/3 the width/height of the original

Comment: I've sort of set it up, I leave it bit bigger on purpose, then I do scaled image to fit the screen correctly. Now I have issues with rotation that works from working path... but that is different problem.